Contributor has lost the "Submit posts for review" feature
Last weekend I had problems with my website, which led me to clean up my WP-OPTIONS table, something I hadn't touched (out of fear) in 13 years. It's incredible how much junk accumulates there, with plugin files loaded into memory for more than a decade, in my case.
After doing a good and careful cleaning, I came across a single error: the WordPress "Contributor" profile has lost the ability to send posts for review. In fact, it doesn't even have the option to enter the posts menu.
I have tried to restore the default permissions for all user types, but it hasn't solved the problem, and I have verified that the assigned permissions are correct. For example, the Contributor role does not have the "Publish posts" permission by default, but if I don't activate it, the posts menu doesn't appear. The problem is that by activating that permission, that profile can publish directly without sending the post for review. This is a problem, because when a new writer joins, during the training phase we have them in that profile before moving them to the author profile.
I've tried a lot of things, including directly editing the wp_user_roles value, to restore the contributor part, but it doesn't work, but I also don't see that in that table there is something that controls the option to send to review.
I've also tried what is indicated in this post Force "Submit to review" when a post is updated, in which they explain how to make an author submit a post for review, changing the part of the code from author to contributor, but it doesn't work either.
My question is... isn't there a way to create a new role with that capability? I have also tried creating a new profile with the default permissions for Contributor, but the result is the same. What controls this function? I understand that this is a problem I created myself by modifying the WP-OPTIONS table, but it should be possible to recover somehow. Thanks a lot!

you mentioned the "Publish posts" permission but can you use the specific exact capability? That phrase could be referring to multiple related things, likewise any changes you made to the wp_user_roles and what you cleaned up. Creating a brand new role is not the answer, what you need to make a new role work would also make the existing role work too. Have you tried resetting the capabilities of the contributor role using WP CLI?

Hi Tom! Thanks a lot for the reply! Yes, that's right, what I really want is to reset the Collaborator role, creating a new role was one of the tests I did to see if the problem was with that role. And no, I haven't used WP CLI. I've never actually used it, if it's really the solution I'd like to try it, but unfortunately I don't have SSH access to my server right now. I can access Plesk panel, database, and the files in my installation.
What I tried was to restore the roles using the options of a couple of role management plugins, which had an option to restore the roles, but didn't work.

you can recreate the site locally with backup downloads, run WP CLI there, then restore the changes to production, it's likely though that unless you know what was wrong you won't be able to solve this with role management plugins, this is how WP CLI does it https://github.com/wp-cli/role-command/blob/main/src/Role_Command.php#L279 though you should look up the contributor role on .org and see the capabilities listed to compare with your own
